# Razor: Get value of selected item in select box

Tags: razor, umbraco, html-select

I have a select box in my view (it is an umbraco partial view),

```
<div class="select">                            
 @{
   var node = Umbraco.Content(1310);
   <select data-val="true" data-val-required="The PickOne field is required." id="PickOne" name="PickOne">
   <option value="">Pick One</option>
   @foreach (var item in node.Children.Where("Visible"))
   {
         <option value="@item.Name">
            @item.Name
         </option>
   }
   </select>
  }                                 
  </div>
```

How can i get selected value of above dropdown in razor?

Please help,

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I got the value in razor, but it appears only after submit

```
 var sLand = Request.Form["PickOne"];
 <p>@sLand</p>
```

How can i make it dynamic (ie, on change)?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a bit a javascript to submit the form onchange. This is what I'm using for a project at the moment.

```
if ($('.select').length) {
    var drpDnwBox = $('.select select');
    drpDnwBox.on('change', function () { $(this).parents('form').submit(); });
}
```

now for the razor (I'm new to this myself)

```
<div class="select">                            
 @{

   var sLand = Request.Form["PickOne"];
   var node = Umbraco.Content(1310);

   <select data-val="true" data-val-required="The PickOne field is required." id="PickOne" name="PickOne">
   <option value="">Pick One</option>
   @foreach (var item in node.Children.Where("Visible"))
   {

        if (sLand.Contains(item.Name)) //using a contains 
        {
            selected = "selected=\"selected\"";
        }

         <option value="@item.Name" @selected>
            @item.Name
         </option>
   }
   </select>
  }                                 
  </div>
```